# How to change property content in array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this array:

```
var arr=[{Id:'3',Status:True, ObjectId:'23'},
         {Id:'4',Status:False, ObjectId:'5'},
         {Id:'5',Status:True, ObjectId:'78'},
         {Id:'6',Status:False, ObjectId:'54'},
         {Id:'7',Status:True, ObjectId:'85'}]
```

The status is `Boolean` type.

In arr variable I need to change the content of all properties.

Where `Status` is `True` I need to set it as Fixed.

Where `Status` is `False` I need to set it as Damaged.

Here is desired result:

```
var arr=[{Id:'3',Status:Fixed, ObjectId:'23'},
         {Id:'4',Status:Damaged, ObjectId:'5'},
         {Id:'5',Status:Fixed, ObjectId:'78'},
         {Id:'6',Status:Damaged, ObjectId:'54'},
         {Id:'7',Status:Fixed, ObjectId:'85'}]
```

What is the best way to implement it?

Comment: is `Fixed` a string?

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach

Use Angular.ForEach as you have mentioned it in the `tags`

```js
var arr=[{Id:'3',Status:true, ObjectId:'23'},
             {Id:'4',Status:false, ObjectId:'5'},
             {Id:'5',Status:true, ObjectId:'78'},
             {Id:'6',Status:false, ObjectId:'54'},
             {Id:'7',Status:true, ObjectId:'85'}]

angular.forEach(arr, function(value, key) {
  value.Status = value.Status ? 'Fixed' : 'Damaged';
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Or without `Angular` you can do

```js
var arr=[{Id:'3',Status:true, ObjectId:'23'},
         {Id:'4',Status:false, ObjectId:'5'},
         {Id:'5',Status:true, ObjectId:'78'},
         {Id:'6',Status:false, ObjectId:'54'},
         {Id:'7',Status:true, ObjectId:'85'}]

arr.forEach(item => item.Status = item.Status ? 'Fixed' : 'Damaged');

console.log(arr);
```

As was mentioned in the comment, this approach will not work in IE 8

[image]

Comment: @Mistalis you are right. For it only stays to loop over an array en manually change everthing

Comment: You can also use `angular.forEach`, it works on all web browsers

Comment: He doesn't use angular

Comment: @Michael I shown you the syntax. See the first code snippet

Answer (score 1):

using `Array.prototype.map(...)`

This is not supported by IE8

```js
var arr = [{
  "Id": '3',
  "Status": true,
  "ObjectId": '23'
}, {
  "Id": '4',
  "Status": false,
  "ObjectId": '5'
}, {
  "Id": '5',
  "Status": true,
  "ObjectId": '78'
}, {
  "Id": '6',
  "Status": false,
  "ObjectId": '54'
}, {
  "Id": '7',
  "Status": true,
  "ObjectId": '85'
}];

arr.map(function(item){
  item.Status = item.Status ? "Fixed" : "Damage";
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Non ES6:

```
arr.map(function(item) {
    item.Status = item.Status ? 'Fixed' : 'Damaged';
    return item;
})
```